# Is there a decent way to convert this SQL query to Python, for using Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a database, which has the imagename, and a hash number. I used the bit_count operator with the bitwise XOR operation to calculate the Hamming Distance and subsequently the similarity index for the images, for which I process them further.

For production, we use a larger database, with about 10 million images, and their hashes, and using elasticsearch seems the fastest, and I am having some trouble figuring out how to convert it into Elasticsearch query in Python using Elasticsearch_dsl

`SELECT imagename, hex(hash), LENGTH(hex(hash)) AS "hash_length",        bit_count(hash ^ 0x1800387EE3414302) AS "hamming_distance",         100 * (1 - bit_count(hash ^ 0x1800387EE3414302) / LENGTH(hex(hash))) AS "similarity_index" FROM hashes WHERE 100 * (1 - bit_count(hash ^ 0x1800387EE3414302) / LENGTH(hex(hash))) >= 75   AND LENGTH(hex(hash)) = LENGTH('1800387EE3414302');`

```
request = Search(using=client, index="hash")

def createSimIndex():
    script_lang = "painless"
    script_name = "simindex"
    script_def = """
            def targetHash = params.targetHash;  // Your target hash in decimal format
            def documentHash = doc['hash'].value;
            def hammingDistance = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 64.0; i++) {  // Assuming unsigned_long is 64 bits
                if (((documentHash >> i) & 1) != ((targetHash >> i) & 1)) {
                hammingDistance++;
                }
            }
            
            // Calculate similarity index as 1 - (hammingDistance / 64)
            def similarityIndex = 1 - (hammingDistance / 64.0);
            return similarityIndex;
        """
    script_def = {
        "script": {
            "lang": script_lang,
            "source": script_def
        }
    }

    client.put_script(id=script_name, body=script_def)

request = request.script_fields(
    simindex = {
        "script": {
            "id": "simindex",
            "params": {
                "targetHash": targetHash[0]
            }
        }
    },
    hash = {
        "script": {
            "id": "giveHash"
        }
    }
)

response = request.scan()
```

Here, I am having some issues, and need more help with:

1. Unable to show the imagename using a simple doc['imagename'].value, which results in a runtime error.
2. Unable to filter where the simindex >= 75
3. One of the hash numbers is quite long, which results in the hash being returned as a negative number in the doc['hash'].value method

I did manage to make it work in Elasticsearch Kibana, but I am unable to figure out how to proceed.

```
POST _scripts/hammingdistance
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
          def targetHash = params.targetHash;  // Your target hash in decimal format
          def dbHash = doc['hash'].value;
          
          
          def hammingDistance = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < 64.0; i++) {  // Assuming unsigned_long is 64 bits
            if (((dbHash >> i) & 1) != ((targetHash >> i) & 1)) {
              hammingDistance++;
            }
          }
          
          //double hammingDistance = documentHash ^ targetHash;
          
          // Check if the hashes are identical
          if (dbHash == targetHash) {
            return 0.0;
          }
          
          
          
          // Calculate similarity index as 1 - (hammingDistance / 64)
          def similarityIndex = 1 - (hammingDistance / 64.0);
          return similarityIndex;
        """
  }
}

GET hash/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "id": "hammingdistance",
        "params": {
          "targetHash": 9073290683095160
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "min_score": 0.75
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using plain Elasticsearch library in Python as compared to Elasticsearch DSL, and just passed the entire query in Python.

Created the script inside elastic with this function (similar to the one in question)

```
def createScript():
    script_lang = "painless"
    script_name = "hammingdistance"
    script_def = """
            def targetHash = params.targetHash;  // Your target hash in decimal format
            def documentHash = doc['hash'].value;
            def hammingDistance = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 64.0; i++) {  // Assuming unsigned_long is 64 bits
                if (((documentHash >> i) & 1) != ((targetHash >> i) & 1)) {
                hammingDistance++;
                }
            }
            
            // Calculate similarity index as 1 - (hammingDistance / 64)
            def similarityIndex = 1 - (hammingDistance / 64.0);
            return similarityIndex;
        """
    script_def = {
        "script": {
            "lang": script_lang,
            "source": script_def
        }
    }

    es.put_script(id=script_name, body=script_def)
```

Sorting and searching in elasticsearch-py as

```
search_param = {
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {
          
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "id": "hammingdistance",
        "params": {
          "targetHash": target
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "min_score": "0.5"
}

response = elastic_client.search(index='hash', body=search_param)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


pp.pprint(response["hits"]["hits"])
print("Highest similarity index: " + str(response["hits"]["max_score"]))
```